# React Router v5: Route defined in child component not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

My application is using react-router-dom v5.3 and I'm having trouble routing from the root url of my application to a child component (called the "See All" Page) while also passing props down. Currently, my code just renders an empty page whenever I navigate to the child component.

RootRouter.js:

```
export default function RootRouter() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
         <Switch>
           <Route
             path="/"
             exact
             render={() => <HomeView />}
           />
         </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Homeview.js:

```
function HomeView() {
    const seeAllViewTitle = "some_title_here"
    return (
        <div>
          <div>Some content here!</div>
          <Link to={`/seeall/${seeAllViewTitle}`}}>
             <Button/>
          </Link>
          <Route path={`/seeall/${seeAllViewTitle}`}>
            <SeeAllView
              groupTitle={""}
              pageData={[]}
              eventHandler={some_function_here}
            />
          </Route>
        </div>
      );
}
```

If I were to put the Route that is currently in homeview.js inside of Rootrouter.js, the component shows up, but I can't pass any props into it from there.

Comment: Remove the `exact` prop from the `Route` in RootRouter. The subroute is currently unreachable because you can't match `/seeall/...` and exactly `/` at the same time. Alternatively, move the `Route` out of HomeView into RootRouter.

Comment: Do you want `HomeView` and `SeeAllView` components rendered at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

## Issue

The `HomeView` component is rendered only when the path is ***exactly*** `"/"`. When the link is clicked and navigates to `"/seeall/some_title_here "` the path no longer exactly matches and the `HomeView` component unmounts.

## Solution

Remove the `exact` prop from the root route so nested/sub routes can also be matched and rendered.

```
export default function RootRouter() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={HomeView} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

If you did not intend for these components to be rendered at the same time then move the nested route out to the `RootRouter` component.

```
export default function RootRouter() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/seeall/:title">
          <SeeAllView
            groupTitle={""}
            pageData={[]}
            eventHandler={some_function_here}
          />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/" component={HomeView} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

...

```
function HomeView() {
  const seeAllViewTitle = "some_title_here"
  return (
    <div>
      <div>Some content here!</div>
      <Link to={`/seeall/${seeAllViewTitle}`}}>
        <Button/>
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you remembering to receive props in the function declaration for HomeView? usually, you'll need to explicitly define that you are receiving props, either with a `props` variable or by defining specific prop names in an object syntax

Comment: Hm I'm not sure what this aims to help with since I don't need to receive any props in the Homeview component, but I need to receive props in the SeeAllView

Comment: i guess i misunderstood the question, i interpreted it as you were trying to load a component on a level and send props, but they were not passing through to the child, I see now that it was indeed a relative path issue with your to='' routes